# Get list of custom object in RemedyForce

Tags: java, android, salesforce

I have custom object in my RemedyForce `abc__c` and would like to get list of it.

Tried this code:

```
SearchResult sr = con.search(
                    "FIND {00008137} IN abc__c FIELDS RETURNING abc__c(Id, Name)");
```

but it returns

> [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault
>   exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='sObject type
>   'abc__c' is not supported. If you are attempting
>   to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.'

Tried this code too and it returns:

```
String sql = "SELECT Id, Name FROM abc__c LIMIT 10";
QueryResult result = con.query(sql);
```

> [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault 
>   exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='sObject type
>   'abc__c' is not supported.'] row='-1' column='-1'
>   ]]

Anyone can advise how to get list of my custom object?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. This exception can happen if the user making the request doesn't have a permission to the specified object.

Comment: I believe the user has permission to the specified object because my colleague can query it by using SOAP UI (myself haven't tested using it though)

Comment: Well i would advise to test it with the same user you running your code

Comment: Another thing to validate is the object is Deployed

Comment: I have checked the object is Deployed. I have also set sessionID in ConnectorConfig that retrieved from login. The one that I am not sure is "You have to check the "Customize Application" checkbox under the same profile."

Comment: @Rendy Another thing to check is that you are using the right WSDL. This exception may happen if you use an Enterprise WSDL from another org.

Comment: Hi Moti, this solved already. It's my fault that I used wrong URL for auth URL lol